# How can I get selected radio button id in angular6

Tags: angular

I am having set of radio buttons. And I need to get id of each radio button after clicking, How can I get radio button id in ts file.. Plz help me

```
<input name="r1" #tradio1 id="r1" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" [value]="0" (change)="Change($event, tradio1)">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="r1">Radio1</label>&nbsp;
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the id as a string param in the **Change()** function?

Comment: Yeah..I got..thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh your Change Function you can use this

```
Change(event, id) {
  console.log(event.target.id)
}
```

Comment: Thank you...I got it...and one thing, here no need to pass id..We will get 'id' within event only. that is event.target.id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngModel directive for this

```
<input name="r1" #tradio1 id="r1" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="yourvariablename" (change)="Change($event, tradio1)">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="r1">Radio1</label>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Querylist and loop with the same id of radio button

```
@ViewChildren('tradio') tradio: QueryList<any>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phckag)**

.html

```
<input name="r1" #tradio1 id="r1" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="radio1value" (ngModelChange)="Change($event)">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="r1">Radio1</label>&nbsp;
```

.ts

```
Change(evt) {
  console.log(evt);
}
```